# React: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function. (onClick)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Error:
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
onClick
src/SidebarChannel.js:12

```
return (
    <div
      className="sidebarChannel"
      onClick={() =>
        dispatch(
          setChannelInfo({
            channelId: id,
```

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setChannelInfo } from "./features/appSlice";
import "./SidebarChannel.css";

function SidebarChannel({ id, channelName }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div
      className="sidebarChannel"
      onClick={() =>
        dispatch(
          setChannelInfo({
            channelId: id,
            channelName: channelName,
          })
        )
      }
    >
      <h4>
        <span className="sidebarChannel__hash">#</span>
        {channelName}
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarChannel;
```

Error is with the onClick on line 12 but I can't figure out how to fix it or what exactly is wrong with it.

Comment: Can you try to add bracts wrapper for dispath like this:
```  onClick={() => {
      dispatch(
        setChannelInfo({
          channelId: id,
          channelName: channelName,
        })
      )
    }
  }```

Comment: Your code looks perfectly right, I'm pretty sure the problem comes from the import of your setChannelInfo function. Double-check that, you will find the mistake.

Comment: Can you post what you're supposedly importing in `setChannelInfo`. We can debug that

Comment: Agreed, I see no issue with this code snippet. Please share the `appSlice` file so we may see how you are exporting your actions.